# Calling python script from Arduino Yun using Process.h

Tags: python-3.x, arduino-yun

I'm a newbie in Arduino and trying to check my python script in Arduino is running or not.

I placed the python script(`sample.py`) in `/mnt/sda1/arduino/www/` which is in SD card.

From the scratch file, I wrote it like below,

```
Process p;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Bridge.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  p.runShellCommandAsynchronously("/usr/bin/python -U /mnt/sda1/arduino/www/sample.py");
  while(p.running());
  if(p.available()>0){
    userInput = p.read();
    Serial.println(userInput);
  }
}
```

And here is my python script code(`sample.py`) on below,

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate = 115200, timeout=1)
ser.write('g')
```

What I'm trying to do here is checking my python script is running. However, it shows nothing on Serial monitor.

What am I doing wrong here..?

Can Anybody help me out here??

Or can anybody give me an example code(scratch code) to check python script is running or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that arduino UNO? If yes, then what kind? what's the clock and memory, what microcontroller does it use (Atmega328??)? Please add more details!

Comment: @UbdusSamad I'm using Arduino Yun. and plugged sd card on the YUN. I'm trying to check my python script from SD card runs appropriately or not. :) Thanks for replying! :)

Comment: Also , in sample.py , replace the last line with `while 1 : ser.write('g')`

Comment: Ah, actually I solved my question.. haha.. I was soooooo stupid.. I don't have to use Serial package in the python code.

Comment: I just checked with creating text file.

like `file = open(full-path, "w")`
`file.write("Hello World")`
`file.close()`

and it worked creating text file in the path that I wrote in full path! :)

Comment: So you directly use print? And please answer your own question formally by writing an answer below!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I made a mistake,
I thought I had to use serial package for checking my python script runs or not.
Rather,
I just used below code for checking.

```
file = open("/mnt/sda1/arduino/www/testfile.txt", "w")

file.write("Hello World")

file.close()
```

Be careful that we have to use full path!!

If you don't, then it will not create a text file.